# Asp.Net Web Api - Returning 404 for IEnumerable<T> Get When null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API using the release version of Asp.Net Web Api.  I am trying to pass back the correct response code (404) if no results are found.

**First Get Version (throws multiple enumeration error):**

```
public IEnumerable<MyObjectType> Get(int id, string format)
{
    var db = new DbEntities();

    var result = db.pr_ApiSelectMyObjectType(store, id, format).AsEnumerable();
    if (result.Any())
    {
        return result;
    }
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) 
        { Content = new StringContent("Unable to find any results") };
    throw new HttpResponseException(response);
}
```

**Second Get Version (result is never null, so it always returns 200):**

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> Get(int id, string format)
{
    var db = new DbEntities();

    var result = db.pr_ApiSelectMyObjectType(store, id, format);
    if (result == null)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) 
            { Content = new StringContent("Unable to find any results") };
        throw new HttpResponseException(response);
    }
    return result.AsEnumerable();
}
```

How do I pass back a 404 if no results are found?  I know I could use a list, but I have a custom csv media type formatter that only works with IEnumerable types, so I would prefer to stick with that.

Answer (score 30):

Better approach is to catch `null` at *action filter level*, define an action filter with global scope, and throw exception 404 from this:

```
public class NullFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var response = actionExecutedContext.Response;

        object responseValue;
        bool hasContent = response.TryGetContentValue(out responseValue);

        if (!hasContent)
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

With this way, you don't need to use `Any` in your action, code would be simpler:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObjectType> Get(int id, string format)
{
    using (db = new DbEntities())
    {
       return db.pr_ApiSelectMyObjectType(store, id, format)
                .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably simplest to just convert the results to a list, which can obviously be enumerated multiple times:

```
var result = db.pr_ApiSelectMyObjectType(store, id, format).ToList();
if (!result.Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Of course that means materializing the whole query... but presumably you'd end up doing that anyway at some point.

Comment: 1. I believe using `result.Count != 0` should be faster as it won't use the `Enumerable`'s `Any` extension method which creates an iterator block but a list's property. 2. With web API v2 and OData you will probably want to return IQueryable and not List (or IEnumerable).

Comment: @gdoron: I believe that `Any()` is optimized for `ICollection<T>` implementations anyway, but it's potentially *much* more efficient than using `Count()` in cases where it's a filtered sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, instead of returning:

```
return result.AsEnumerable();
```

you can return null:

```
return null;
```

and from the calling function, you check the returned result something like:

```
var myObject = Get(id, format);
if (myObject == null)
    return NotFound(myObject);
else
    return Ok(myObject);
```

By doing so you will get 404 not found if Get function can't find the record.